# why did my sqlplus keeps on getting disconnected when im putting the scott.sql directory

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsI20.png)

im trying to figure out how to add scott schema into my oracle db, but when i try it this way by adding the directory in sqlplus it keeps on getting disconnected for some reason.

and scott is not yet added after i tried disconnecting and connecting it again when i use the select username from all_users; command.
<<scott.sql contents>>

```
Rem Copyright (c) 1990 by Oracle Corporation
Rem NAME
REM    UTLSAMPL.SQL
Rem  FUNCTION
Rem  NOTES
Rem  MODIFIED
Rem gdudey     06/28/95 -  Modified for desktop seed database
Rem glumpkin   10/21/92 -  Renamed from SQLBLD.SQL
Rem blinden   07/27/92 -  Added primary and foreign keys to EMP and DEPT
Rem rlim       04/29/91 -         change char to varchar2
Rem mmoore     04/08/91 -         use unlimited tablespace priv
Rem pritto     04/04/91 -         change SYSDATE to 13-JUL-87
Rem   Mendels    12/07/90 - bug 30123;add to_date calls so language     independent
Rem
rem
rem $Header: rdbms/common_nt/sql/scott.sql /main/3 2020/07/20 03:48:35     dgoddard Exp $ sqlbld.sql
rem
SET TERMOUT OFF
SET ECHO OFF

rem CONGDON    Invoked in RDBMS at build time.   29-DEC-1988
rem OATES:     Created: 16-Feb-83

GRANT CONNECT,RESOURCE,UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO SCOTT IDENTIFIED BY     TIGER;
ALTER USER SCOTT DEFAULT TABLESPACE USERS;
ALTER USER SCOTT TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP;
rem CONNECT SCOTT/TIGER
CONNECT SCOTT/TIGER@xepdb1
DROP TABLE DEPT;
CREATE TABLE DEPT
       (DEPTNO NUMBER(2) CONSTRAINT PK_DEPT PRIMARY KEY,
    DNAME VARCHAR2(14) ,
    LOC VARCHAR2(13) ) ;
DROP TABLE EMP;
CREATE TABLE EMP
       (EMPNO NUMBER(4) CONSTRAINT PK_EMP PRIMARY KEY,
    ENAME VARCHAR2(10),
    JOB VARCHAR2(9),
    MGR NUMBER(4),
    HIREDATE DATE,
    SAL NUMBER(7,2),
    COMM NUMBER(7,2),
    DEPTNO NUMBER(2) CONSTRAINT FK_DEPTNO REFERENCES DEPT);
INSERT INTO DEPT VALUES
    (10,'ACCOUNTING','NEW YORK');
INSERT INTO DEPT VALUES (20,'RESEARCH','DALLAS');
INSERT INTO DEPT VALUES
    (30,'SALES','CHICAGO');
INSERT INTO DEPT VALUES
    (40,'OPERATIONS','BOSTON');
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
(7369,'SMITH','CLERK',7902,to_date('17-12-1980','dd-mm-    yyyy'),800,NULL,20);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
(7499,'ALLEN','SALESMAN',7698,to_date('20-2-1981','dd-mm-    yyyy'),1600,300,30);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
(7521,'WARD','SALESMAN',7698,to_date('22-2-1981','dd-mm-    yyyy'),1250,500,30);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
(7566,'JONES','MANAGER',7839,to_date('2-4-1981','dd-mm-    yyyy'),2975,NULL,20);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
(7654,'MARTIN','SALESMAN',7698,to_date('28-9-1981','dd-mm-    yyyy'),1250,1400,30);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
(7698,'BLAKE','MANAGER',7839,to_date('1-5-1981','dd-mm-    yyyy'),2850,NULL,30);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
(7782,'CLARK','MANAGER',7839,to_date('9-6-1981','dd-mm-    yyyy'),2450,NULL,10);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
(7788,'SCOTT','ANALYST',7566,to_date('13-JUL-87')-85,3000,NULL,20);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
(7839,'KING','PRESIDENT',NULL,to_date('17-11-1981','dd-mm-    yyyy'),5000,NULL,10);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
(7844,'TURNER','SALESMAN',7698,to_date('8-9-1981','dd-mm-    yyyy'),1500,0,30);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
(7876,'ADAMS','CLERK',7788,to_date('13-JUL-87')-51,1100,NULL,20);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
(7900,'JAMES','CLERK',7698,to_date('3-12-1981','dd-mm-    yyyy'),950,NULL,30);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
(7902,'FORD','ANALYST',7566,to_date('3-12-1981','dd-mm-    yyyy'),3000,NULL,20);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES
(7934,'MILLER','CLERK',7782,to_date('23-1-1982','dd-mm-    yyyy'),1300,NULL,10);
DROP TABLE BONUS;
CREATE TABLE BONUS
    (
    ENAME VARCHAR2(10)  ,
    JOB VARCHAR2(9)  ,
    SAL NUMBER,
    COMM NUMBER
    ) ;
DROP TABLE SALGRADE;
CREATE TABLE SALGRADE
      ( GRADE NUMBER,
    LOSAL NUMBER,
    HISAL NUMBER );
INSERT INTO SALGRADE VALUES (1,700,1200);
INSERT INTO SALGRADE VALUES (2,1201,1400);
INSERT INTO SALGRADE VALUES (3,1401,2000);
INSERT INTO SALGRADE VALUES (4,2001,3000);
INSERT INTO SALGRADE VALUES (5,3001,9999);
COMMIT;

SET TERMOUT ON
SET ECHO ON
```

Comment: well we don't know what the scott.sql script does but probably logs out

Comment: i dont think it is

Comment: It is, but indirectly. Possibly the user creation is failing, but it could be something else; but when it does `CONNECT SCOTT/TIGER@xepdb1` that isn't working and it's leaving you disconnected. It could be that the `@xepdb1` isn't correct, or you don't have a `tnsnames.ora` in the right place or with the right value, or the user wasn't created, etc. If you make a copy of that script and comment out the `SET TERMOUT OFF` then you'll be able to see what it's actually complaining about.

Comment: Also, is there a reason you're using `SCOTT`, not the [current sample schemas](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/comsc/introduction-to-sample-schemas.html#GUID-844E92D8-A4C8-4522-8AF5-761D4BE99200)? You might want `HR` rather than `SCOTT`. The [instructions for those](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/comsc/installing-sample-schemas.html#GUID-3820972A-08D7-4033-9524-1E36676594EE) specify connect as `sys as sysdba`, which you aren't doing - connecting as `system` might not give you the privs you need.

Comment: you need to connect to the PDB and not the container, try this
connect system/password@localhost:1521/xepdb1